# REPLACE a given occurance of a string in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a column like this:

```
vars
-----------
|A|B|A|D|AB|B...
```

I want to replace one var (e.g: the one in 3rd position, which happens to be A) but keep any other A's. The position is determined by a variable. So I should get:

```
vars
-----------
|A|B|D|AB|B...
```

I know I should use REPLACE and possibly SUBSTRING_INDEX, but I can't figure out how. Here's what I've tried:
Let's say :pos=3;

```
vars = REPLACE(vars, (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(vars, '|', :pos), '|', -1)), '')
```

But this actually replaces all other characters and keeps the one I need replaced.

UPDATE: Mind that I don't know what var I want to replace, only its position.

UPDATE 2:

```
vars = Concat(substring(vars ,1,:pos-1), substring(vars,:pos+2))
```

This does the trick but I forgot to mention the vars are not always |A and |B etc., but also |AB, |AC... So the position shouldn't always move by one character, but until the next `|`.

Comment: can you add some code that you tried

Comment: Do you want to replace only 'A' specifically, or you want to replace all duplicate characters?

Comment: Your data model is broken. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutly yes!**

Comment: Sisir Ranjan, just that one occurrence of A which is in the set position (in the variable $pos for example).

Comment: @user1542894 look at my ans. replace string with your column name

Comment: Zohar Peled, yes I see. But I've already implemented this model in this situation. I will know in the future.

Comment: if my ans is worked you should accept it

Answer (score 1):

if you know position  number `6` is your position variable

```
SELECT  concat(SUBSTRING('|A|B|A|D|G|B',1,6-2),SUBSTRING('|A|B|A|D|G|B',6+1) )
```

or if you know string at second occurrence

```
    SELECT REPLACE( '|A|B|A|D|G|B', concat( SUBSTRING_INDEX( '|A|B|A|D|G|B', 
'|A', 2 ) , "|A" ) , SUBSTRING_INDEX( '|A|B|A|D|G|B', '|A', 2 ) )
```

Comment: I don't know the actual var, just its position.

Comment: what is the position ?

Comment: It's a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help, both you and Nishanth Matha helped and I would accept both answers if I could, but his came a minute earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139763/discussion-between-user1542894-and-knowledge).

Comment: Yours but he edited his first. But seems that I still can't make it work the way I want to using `vars = CONACT(SUBSTRING(vars ,1,:pos-1), SUBSTRING(vars,LOCATE('|','vars', :pos+1)))`, so the question remains open.

Comment: I've updated the question: "the vars are not always |A and |B etc., but also |AB, |AC... So the position shouldn't always move by one character, but until the next |"

Comment: add some example so i can understand

Answer (score 1):

As @Zohar said, I agree your model is broken. Yet, if you want to achieve, here's an example with `locate`, `substring`, `concat`:

First `locate` the index of first `|A` the second `|A` will always be after it.

> `locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B', locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B')+1)`
>
> -- here +1 denotes after first index

Second find the `sub-string after the second occurrence of |A`

> `substring('|A|B|A|D|G|B',locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B', locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B')+1)+2)`
>
> --here +2 denotes the length of your string with is `|A`

Third find the `sub-string before the second occurrence of |A`

> `substring('|A|B|A|D|G|B',locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B', 1,locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B')+1)-1)`
>
> -- here -1 denotes any thing from the beginning to the charecter before `|A`

Fourth, `concat` the string after and before the second occurrence of `|A`

> ```
> Concat(
>   substring('|A|B|A|D|G|B',locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B',1,locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B')+1)-1),
>   substring('|A|B|A|D|G|B',locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B', locate('|A','|A|B|A|D|G|B')+1)+2)
> )
> ```

**EDIT 1:** Like in your update if you ready know the position you can simply do:

> ```
> vars = Concat(substring(vars ,1,:pos-1), substring(vars,:pos+2))
> ```

***EDIT 2:***

With your comment if you need to replace till next `|` you can do use both `location` and `substring` something like:

```
vars = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(vars ,1,:pos-1), SUBSTRING(vars,LOCATE('|',vars, :pos+1)))
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/97882/0)

Comment: `vars = Concat(substring(vars ,1,:pos-1), substring(vars,:pos+2))`

This works but I forgot to mention another thing: The vars are not always `|A` and `|B` etc., but also `|AB`, `|AC`... So the pos shouldn't always move by one character, but untill the next `|`.

Comment: This actually deletes everything in the column.

Comment: @user1542894 there was a typo in the ans . Try the edit it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result I wanted by using php instead. I already had $vars exploded into an array in the code and then just used unset($vars[$pos]) to remove the var at the set position.